# Outline colspan in major browsers?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm curious what the impact is of colspan in different browsers.

I have a table with a row acting as a heading which uses colspan to spread across all columns, and I might want to add columns in the future. If I simply make the colspan some really large number so that I can add columns without having to update the heading, does this have any negative impacts?

Will browsers behave badly and creating loads of dud columns, or should they be smart enough to limit this to how many columns the table actually has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `colspan` to span columns that have no cells beginning in them violates the HTML table model (which is being formalized in HTML5 [table processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#processing-model-1)). All bets are off then, and testing on all existing browsers (which isn’t really possible) wouldn’t be enough – future browsers could handle your markup error differently.

Theoretically, according to HTML 4.01, `colspan=0` means that “the cell spans all columns from the current column to the last column of the column group (COLGROUP) in which the cell is defined”. However, this was not implemented, and it is being removed (value of 0 made an error) in HTML5, without any replacement.

The idea is clearly that the author, or the software that generates an HTML document, is responsible for counting the columns. That is, if you add columns to the table, you need to modify the `colspan` value, if you want a cell to span all columns.

Answer (score 1):

MDN says there are two behaviors, one for `<th>` and one for `<td>`.

For [header cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) (`th`), the value must be >=0, <=1000.  If it is >1000 it *clips to 1000*, if it is 0 it spans the entire `<colgroup>`.

For [data cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) (`td`), the value value must be >= 0, <= 1000.  If it is >1000 it is *set to 1*, if it is 0 it spans the entire `<colgroup>`.

Also, it appears Firefox is the only one to support the 0 = colgroup rule.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to try it. But my guess is they'll all be fine.

What's a really large number? 50? 100? 10000?

here's a fiddle with 200 columns and a colspan:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="200">test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FYKqb/

try it in different browsers. I reckon they'd all be fine.

Comment: I know that works, but I'm wondering if there are any horrible implications from doing so? Like chewing up a lot of memory in the browser creating unnecessary columns, or are most browsers smart enough not to create columns not needed?